# error calling tpl: error during tpl function execution for "configuration.yaml.default (home assistant helm upgrade on truenas scale)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, home-assistant

I'm having trouble trying to update my home assistant with truecharts.

```
[EFAULT] Failed to upgrade chart release: 
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: 
template: commonloader.apply" at : 
error calling include: 
template: home-assistant/charts/common/templates/spawner/_configmap.tpl:16:10: 
executing "tc.common.spawner.configmap" at : 
error calling include: template: home-assistant/charts/common/templates/class/_configmap.tpl:33:6: executing "tc.common.class.configmap" at : 
error calling tpl: error during tpl function execution for "configuration.yaml.default: 
{{- if hasKey .Values \"ixChartContext\" }}
 - {{ .Values.ixChartContext.kubernetes_config.cluster_cidr }}
 {{- else }}
 {{- range .Values.homeassistant.trusted_proxies }}
 - {{ . }}
 {{- end }}
 {{- end }}
init.sh: |-
 #!/bin/sh
 if test -f \"/config/configuration.yaml\"; then
 echo \"configuration.yaml exists.\"
 if grep -q recorder: \"/config/configuration.yaml\"; then
 echo \"configuration.yaml already contains recorder\"
 else
 cat /config/init/recorder.default >> /config/configuration.yaml
 fi
 if grep -q http: \"/config/configuration.yaml\"; then
 echo \"configuration.yaml already contains http section\"
 else
 cat /config/init/http.default >> /config/configuration.yaml
 fi
 else
 echo \"configuration.yaml does NOT exist.\"
 cp /config/init/configuration.yaml.default /config/configuration.yaml
 cat /config/init/recorder.default >> /config/configuration.yaml
 cat /config/init/http.default >> /config/configuration.yaml
 fi
 echo \"Creating include files...\"
 for include_file in groups.yaml automations.yaml scripts.yaml scenes.yaml; do
 if test -f \"/config/$include_file\"; then
 echo \"$include_file exists.\"
 else
 echo \"$include_file does NOT exist.\"
 touch \"/config/$include_file\"
 fi
 done
 cd \"/config\" || echo \"Could not change path to /config\"
 echo \"Creating custom_components directory...\"
 mkdir \"/config/custom_components\" || echo \"custom_components directory already exists\"
 echo \"Changing to the custom_components directory...\"
 cd \"/config/custom_components\" || echo \"Could not change path to /config/custom_components\"
 echo \"Downloading HACS\"
 wget \"https://github.com/hacs/integration/releases/latest/download/hacs.zip\" || exit 0
 if [ -d \"/config/custom_components/hacs\" ]; then
 echo \"HACS directory already exist, cleaning up...\"
 rm -R \"/config/custom_components/hacs\"
 fi
 echo \"Creating HACS directory...\"
 mkdir \"/config/custom_components/hacs\"
 echo \"Unpacking HACS...\"
 unzip \"/config/custom_components/hacs.zip\" -d \"/config/custom_components/hacs\" >/dev
ull 2>&1
 echo \"Removing HACS zip file...\"
 rm \"/config/custom_components/hacs.zip\"
 echo \"Installation complete.\"
recorder.default: |2-
 recorder:
 purge_keep_days: 30
 commit_interval: 3
 db_url: {{ ( printf \"%s?client_encoding=utf8\" ( .Values.postgresql.url.complete | trimAll \"\\\"\" ) ) | quote }}": template: home-assistant/templates/common.yaml:19:18: executing "home-assistant/templates/common.yaml" at <.Values.ixChartContext.kubernetes_config.cluster_cidr>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.cluster_cidr
```

I tried chmod 755 on the custom_components directory and also tried to use the bare minimum for the configuration.yaml.  Still got the same error. Is there a way I can run a debug on this?  Anyone have any ideas?